# Maximum track binary tree

Tags: java

-- java --
for the tree

> ```
>      5
>   4     3
> 30  5
> ```

I need to find the "Maximum track"
so for this tree, its 39 (5+4+30)

i need a function that do that (Complexity O(n))
can someone help me?

```
public static int GetTreePath(BinTreeNode<Integer> t){
        if (t==null)
            return 0;

        if (t.IsLeve()){
            return t.getInfo();
        }else{
            GetTreePath(t.getLeft());
            GetTreePath(t.getRight());
        }
        return t.getInfo();
    }
```

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it a such. Hint: look into recursive algorithms.

Comment: And you might want to post some code, show the community what you have so far instead of vaguely asking for help.

Comment: Ok here is my code. I have not posted it because I think it is not even close to an answer

Comment: Please stick to Jaa naming conventions.

Comment: @JBNizet: Typically we call it "Java".  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just modified your code a bit in order to get the maximum of both possible subtrees.

```
public static int GetTreePath(BinTreeNode<Integer> t){
    if (t==null)
        return 0;

    if (t.IsLeve()){
        return t.getInfo();
    }else{
        return Math.max(
            GetTreePath(t.getLeft()), 
            GetTreePath(t.getRight()) 
            ) + t.getInfo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a DP solution.

```
F(i) = max(F(child) + value(i))
```

`calculate(f)` from the leaves to the root,or recursion and save the `f(i)`